# My Arduino automatic LED 'nightlight' is not working

Tags: arduino, processing, led, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno, and I'm trying to write a program where if the photoresistor detects a low amount of light, an LED turns on. Here is my code.

```
int led = 2;
int phores = A4;
int val = 0;

void setup() {
 pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(phores, INPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 val = analogRead(phores);
 if(val > 256) {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
}

if(val < 256) {

digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}
Serial.println(val);
}
```

Comment: ... and what happens?  Does it crash, or not give the expected answer?  What did you EXPECT to happen, and what HAPPENED?

Comment: What is the output of your println? Is the value reading correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put the second if block inside the loop function. I'm pretty certain that should fix things. Adding a small delay might also be a good idea to avoid doing this check at every iteration.

Comment: I didn't put the 2nd if statement inside the if block, and adding a delay didn't help.

Comment: I mean void loop block, not if block. :&

Answer (score 0):

I have some old code that I used when I started learning, this should work and is real simple.

```
int sensePin = 0;
int ledPin = 9;

void setup(){
  analogReference(DEFAULT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){
  int val = analogRead(sensePin);
 if (val < 100) digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
 else digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
```